# Fix overflow of div and adjust other elements

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I am writing some HTML code and CSS code to display song data. For instance, the song name, artist, duration, etc... However, I realized that if I have a long song name then it overflows to the next line which is good. Though I noticed that when it does overflow then it will leak into the next element. So I am actively trying to find a way to adjust the other elements so non overlap. I realized I have my positioning as `absolute`, but even when I change my position style from `absolute` to `relative`, it still overlaps the values.

Below the code:

```css
body {
    color: black;
    
}



.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}


.split-left {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: orange;
    /* background-color: #f8f7f4; */
}


.split-right {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
    right: 0;
    background-color:red;
    /* background-color:#f7f1e3; */
}

.tyler-selected {
    width: 270px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: blue;
    box-shadow: 0 13px 16px 0 rgba(255, 203, 25, 0.25);
}




.tyler-regular {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #ccc;
    padding: 1px 1px;
    background-color: #f2f1ec;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 0.5s;

}

.tyler-regular:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    background-color: #ffcb19;
    
}


.song-box {
    width: 40%;
    height: 30%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 20px;
    size: 30px;
}




.song {
    margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    
}


.dayOfWeek {
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
}


.company-name {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 25%;
}

.song-name {
    margin: 7px 20px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.artist-name {
    margin: 7px 20px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
}



/*******************************/
    /*
    *   RIGHT SIDE 
    */
/*******************************/



.image-box {
    /* margin: 260px 960px 210px 130px; */
    width: 570px;
    height: 570px;
}


img {
    height: 570px;
    object-fit: contain;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 46px 0 rgba(255, 203, 25, 0.3);
}



.track-data{
    display: inline;
}



header {
    background-color: #14213d;
}

header::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;

}

nav {
    float: right;
}



nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}






nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 35px;
    padding-top: 10px;

    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}




nav a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 23px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;


}

li::after {
    background-color: white;
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: width 0.35s ease 0s;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  li:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
  }
  


.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #ccc;
    padding: 1px 1px;
    background-color: #f2f1ec;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 0.5s;
}



.song-box-main {
    width: 40%;
    height: 30%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    size: 30px;
}


.test {
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 46px rgba(255, 203, 25, 0.30196078431372547));
    width: 570px;
    height: 570px;
    left: 340px;
    top: 255px;
}


.song-data {
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 306.00px;
    height: 491.00px;
    left: 1040.00px;
    top: 335.00px;
}

.week {
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    margin-top: 0.00px;
    margin-right: 0.00px;
    padding-top: 0.00px;
    font-size: 40.00px;
    font-weight: 400;
  
    
}


.song-box-data {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 140.00px;
    height: 43.00px;
    left: 0.00px;
    top: 83.00px;
}

.song-styles {
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -ms-transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: default;
    margin-top: 0.00px;
    margin-right: 0.00px;
    margin-bottom: 0.00px;
    margin-left: 0.00px;
    padding-top: 0.00px;
    padding-right: 0.00px;
    padding-bottom: 0.00px;
    padding-left: 0.00px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing: 0.63px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8705882352941177);
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1.00px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 21.00px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Eina01-SemiBold, Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    overflow-x: unset;
    overflow-y: unset;
    white-space: pre;
    width: 64.00px;
    height: 21.00px;
    left: 52.00px;
    top: 13.00px;
}


.rectangle-1 {
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -ms-transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    background-image: url(./img/rectangle16.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: default;
    margin-top: 0.00px;
    margin-right: 0.00px;
    margin-bottom: 0.00px;
    margin-left: 0.00px;
    padding-top: 0.00px;
    padding-right: 0.00px;
    padding-bottom: 0.00px;
    padding-left: 0.00px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(112, 112, 112, 1);
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-bottom-width: 1.00px;
    border-left-color: rgba(112, 112, 112, 1);
    border-left-style: none;
    border-left-width: 1.00px;
    border-right-color: rgba(112, 112, 112, 1);
    border-right-style: none;
    border-right-width: 1.00px;
    border-top-color: rgba(112, 112, 112, 1);
    border-top-style: none;
    border-top-width: 1.00px;
    border-top-left-radius: 25.00px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25.00px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25.00px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25.00px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 13px 16px rgba(255, 203, 25, 0.25098039215686274));
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 13px 16px rgba(255, 203, 25, 0.25098039215686274));
    width: 140.00px;
    height: 43.00px;
    left: 0.00px;
    top: 0.00px;
}


.music-icon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -ms-transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    background-image: url(./img/music.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: default;
    margin-top: 0.00px;
    margin-right: 0.00px;
    margin-bottom: 0.00px;
    margin-left: 0.00px;
    padding-top: 0.00px;
    padding-right: 0.00px;
    padding-bottom: 0.00px;
    padding-left: 0.00px;
    overflow-x: unset;
    overflow-y: unset;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 19.02px;
    height: 19.47px;
    left: 21.00px;
    top: 11.53px;
}


.seeYouAgain {
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -ms-transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: default;
    margin-top: 0.00px;
    margin-right: 0.00px;
    margin-bottom: 0.00px;
    margin-left: 0.00px;
    padding-top: 0.00px;
    padding-right: 0.00px;
    padding-bottom: 0.00px;
    padding-left: 0.00px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing: 1.02px;
    color: rgba(38, 38, 43, 1);
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1.00px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 34.00px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Eina01-Bold, Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    overflow-x: unset;
    overflow-y: unset;
    white-space: pre;
    width: 234.00px;
    height: 34.00px;
    left: 0.00px;
    top: 161.00px;
}


.artist-line {

    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 306.00px;
    height: 21.00px;
    left: 0.00px;
    top: 225.00px;
}


.by {

    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -ms-transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: default;
    margin-top: 0.00px;
    margin-right: 0.00px;
    margin-bottom: 0.00px;
    margin-left: 0.00px;
    padding-top: 0.00px;
    padding-right: 0.00px;
    padding-bottom: 0.00px;
    padding-left: 0.00px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing: 0.63px;
    color: rgba(38, 38, 43, 1);
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1.00px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 21.00px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Eina02-SemiBold, Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    overflow-x: unset;
    overflow-y: unset;
    white-space: pre;
    width: 32.00px;
    height: 21.00px;
    left: 0.00px;
    top: 0.00px;
}



.artist-line-name {
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -ms-transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    opacity: 0.9961829781532288;
    cursor: default;
    margin-top: 0.00px;
    margin-right: 0.00px;
    margin-bottom: 0.00px;
    margin-left: 0.00px;
    padding-top: 0.00px;
    padding-right: 0.00px;
    padding-bottom: 0.00px;
    padding-left: 0.00px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing: 0.63px;
    color: rgba(110, 85, 2, 1);
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1.00px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 21.00px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    overflow-x: unset;
    overflow-y: unset;
    width: 274.00px;
    height: 21.00px;
    left: 32.00px;
    top: 0.00px;
}


.time-info {

    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 112.00px;
    height: 55.00px;
    left: 2.00px;
    top: 276.00px;
}

.duration {

    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -ms-transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    opacity: 0.4025520086288452;
    cursor: default;
    margin-top: 0.00px;
    margin-right: 0.00px;
    margin-bottom: 0.00px;
    margin-left: 0.00px;
    padding-top: 0.00px;
    padding-right: 0.00px;
    padding-bottom: 0.00px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing: 0.42px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8705882352941177);
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1.00px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 14.00px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Eina01-SemiBold, Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    overflow-x: unset;
    overflow-y: unset;
    white-space: pre;
    width: 75.00px;
    height: 14.00px;
    left: 31.00px;
    top: 2.00px;
}

.minutes {

    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -ms-transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: default;
    margin-top: 0.00px;
    margin-right: 0.00px;
    margin-bottom: 0.00px;
    margin-left: 0.00px;
    padding-top: 0.00px;
    padding-right: 0.00px;
    padding-bottom: 0.00px;
    padding-left: 0.00px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing: 0.60px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8705882352941177);
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1.00px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 20.00px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Eina01-SemiBold, Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    overflow-x: unset;
    overflow-y: unset;
    white-space: pre;
    width: 81.00px;
    height: 20.00px;
    left: 31.00px;
    top: 35.00px;
}


.clock {

    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -ms-transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    transform: rotate(0.00deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    background-image: url(assets/clock.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: default;
    margin-top: 0.00px;
    margin-right: 0.00px;
    margin-bottom: 0.00px;
    margin-left: 0.00px;
    padding-top: 0.00px;
    padding-right: 0.00px;
    padding-bottom: 0.00px;
    padding-left: 0.00px;
    overflow-x: unset;
    overflow-y: unset;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 18.00px;
    height: 18.00px;
    left: -1.00px;
    top: -1.00px;
}
```

```html
   
<body>


    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Donations</a></li>
                <li><a href='contact.html'>Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>



  
    
<div class="split-left">

    <div class="company-name">
        <span style="font-size: 48px;">
            <i class="fas fa-headphones"></i>
        </span>
        <h1 style="display: inline-block;">BueField</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="random">
        <div class="tyler-regular">
            <p class="dayOfWeek">Monday</p>
            <div class="song-box">
                <span style="color: #2C3A47; margin-left: 22px; font-size: 14px;">
                    <i class="fas fa-music"></i>
                </span>              
                <p class="song">Song</p>
            </div>
            <p class="song-name">See you again</p>
            <p class="artist-name">By: Love me for your life</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tyler-regular">
            <p class="dayOfWeek">Tuesday</p>
            <div class="song-box">
                <span style="color: #2C3A47; margin-left: 22px; font-size: 14px;">
                    <i class="fas fa-music"></i>
                </span>              
                <p class="song">Song</p>
            </div>
            <p class="song-name">See you again</p>
            <p class="artist-name">By: Love me for your life</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tyler-regular">
            <p class="dayOfWeek">Wednesday</p>
            <div class="song-box">
                <span style="color: #2C3A47; margin-left: 22px; font-size: 14px;">
                    <i class="fas fa-music"></i>
                </span>              
                <p class="song">Song</p>
            </div>
            <p class="song-name">See you again</p>
            <p class="artist-name">By: Love me for your life</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tyler-regular">
            <p class="dayOfWeek">Thursday</p>
            <div class="song-box">
                <span style="color: #2C3A47; margin-left: 22px; font-size: 14px;">
                    <i class="fas fa-music"></i>
                </span>              
                <p class="song">Song</p>
            </div>
            <p class="song-name">See you again</p>
            <p class="artist-name">By: Love me for your life</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tyler-regular">
            <p class="dayOfWeek">Friday</p>
            <div class="song-box">
                <span style="color: #2C3A47; margin-left: 22px; font-size: 14px;">
                    <i class="fas fa-music"></i>
                </span>              
                <p class="song">Song</p>
            </div>
            <p class="song-name">See you again</p>
            <p class="artist-name">By: Love me for your life</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    

</div>
  









<div class="split-right">


    


    
    
        <div class="test">
            <img src="./img/giveon-art.jpeg" alt="Spotify Cover Art">
        </div>

        <div class="song-data">
            <h2 class="week">Monday</h2>



            <div class="song-box-data">
                <div class="rectangle-1"></div>
                <p class="song-styles">Song</p>
                <div class="music-icon"></div>
                
            </div>
            <p class="seeYouAgain">See You Again</p>
                <div class="artist-line">                
                    <div class="by">By:</div>
                    <div class="artist-line-name">Wiz Knalifa ft. Charlie This is too show that when i have a really really really long string it starts to overlap the other elements in the html</div>
                </div>
                <div class="time-info">                
                    <div class="duration">Duration</div>
                    <div class="minutes">4:54 min</div>
                    <div class="clock">
                        <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <audio controls>
                    <source src="https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/9597944813e1a32cc263cc55ccd20153f2b6fa82?cid=907576181422448e91e222b424ba898a" type="audio/mp3">
                </audio>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</body>
```

Comment: You can use CSS Shorthand to reduce your code quite a bit.  For example `margin: 0;` takes care of all 4 margins and `overflow: unset;` takes care of overflow x and y, etc.

Comment: Clarify what is going wrong with your code here and what you want.  You talk about long song names, but your code here has a short song name and a long artist name.  Seems like your issue is more positioning of your elements and audio controls but it's not clear.

Comment: @ChrisL Yes, sorry about the confusion Chris. The main issue I am having is confusion, although the code I gave does not show exactly the problem this is the exact CSS I use in my actual code. Although I have a short song name here the problem is when I have a longer name, it starts to overlap other elements such as duration or artist.

Comment: well show that in your code here.  create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue

Comment: @ChrisL Hey Chris, I made the needed adjustments to view the code and the error I receive

Comment: get rid of all of your fixed height and widths and your absolute positioning and you will have something [like this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/xdr127g0/)